# ASP.NET MVC I would like to redirect to another action passing my model to it, to get the right URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to pass my model to my view back after a validation error. To perform this, I call the action that checks validation:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult CreateIncident(IncidentModel incident)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string response = _incidentService.CreateIncident(incident).Value;
            if (response.Length == 15)
            {
                TempData["Message"] = String.Format($"Le ticket {response} a bien été réceptionné par l'équipe support");
                TempData["Class"] = "success";
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Une erreur est survenue lors de la création de l'incident";
                TempData["Class"] = "warning";
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        TempData["Message"] = "Attention, vous n'avez pas saisi toutes les informations requises.";
        TempData["Class"] = "warning";

        return View("Index", incident);
    }
```

And is supposed to send my model back to my view in case of wrong validation:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Karanga";
        return View("Index", new IncidentModel());
    }
```

To the same view I posted my model from.

The problem here is when I call Index() my URL is */Incident/Index* (default route) and everything's fine. 
But then I call CreatIncident() and my URL becomes like */Incident/CreateIncident*.
I really need it to be correct because I use it in order to set the active menu button for example.

I tried redirecting to action Index, hoping my model could be stored in cache, but if it has been working, I wouldn't be asking for help here.

Is it possible to redirect passing my model as a parameter?

If you have any idea about how I can fix this, by redirecting to action Index, preferably without passing my model in the TempData (but if there is no other solution, I'll do it), it will help.

Comment: You want the Index view to remain persistent while switching out smaller views beneath it? A search on @Ajax.BeginForm and PartialViews may be beneficial. You can RedirectToAction that returns a PartialView, however, to have the url remain intact you will have to leave Index intact. That may or may not be what you desire?

Comment: DO not store a model in cache. This is a bad idea. And yes you can pass a model as a parameter to a `ActionResult`. Just use `return View("Index", "incident",new{ model});`

Comment: Just follow convention and rename the post method to `public ActionResult Index(IncidentModel incident)` to match the GET method (or change the GET method to `public ActionResult CreateIncident()`

Comment: Thanks Stephen, you helped me twice in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make your Index method do double-duty? Something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index(IncidentModel incident = null)
{
    if (incident == null) {
        ViewBag.Title = "Karanga";
        return View("Index", new IncidentModel());
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string response = _incidentService.CreateIncident(incident).Value;
        if (response.Length == 15)
        {
            TempData["Message"] = String.Format($"Le ticket {response} a bien été réceptionné par l'équipe support");
            TempData["Class"] = "success";
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "Une erreur est survenue lors de la création de l'incident";
            TempData["Class"] = "warning";
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    TempData["Message"] = "Attention, vous n'avez pas saisi toutes les informations requises.";
    TempData["Class"] = "warning";

    return View("Index", incident);
}
```

Then your form action would be:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index")) {
...
}
```

In our applications where we want to post the data but not reload the screen we'll grab the form data, and send it to the server using a JavaScript post. Then the server is updated with the latest data while the client page did not change nor reload.

This can also allow you to retrieve the result from the server as Json, and update any form fields or read/only values as needed.